# Powershell WPF works perfectly from ISE, but not when run as compiled EXE

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have a small issue here that I’m struggling to figure out how to solve :)

My «script»/application is supposed to replace some text on specific lines in a configuration-file (PATH+$TESTalias)
I’ve made a wpf-form which contains a listbox(displaying some names) a OK and a cancel-button.

I’ve made a hashtable containing «aliases» for the displayed names in the listbox.
And made it so that when the okay-button is clicked, the alias for the selected item in the listbox is to be stored into a variable, which in turn will then be used in the «path+$TESTalias"

And everything works perfectly when launched locally through ISE.

But when I «compile» the «application» to a EXE-file (either through ISESteroids or PS2EXE) only the first part of the path is changed and NOT the $TESTalias variable.

I’ve tried declaring it as a global-script-variable as well, with the same result.

Can’t post the actual names/locations here, but have now posted a slightly revised script to not disclose any sensitive information.

The puzzling part for me is that it works perfectly when run from ISE but NOT after exe-compilation

```
# Find currently logged on user
$Loggedon = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Class Win32_Computersystem | Select-Object UserName
# Split domain and username.
$Domain,$User = $Loggedon.Username.split('\',2)



# NOTE: When you use a SPECIFIC catch block, exceptions thrown by -ErrorAction Stop MAY LACK
# some InvocationInfo details such as ScriptLineNumber.
# REMEDY: If that affects you, remove the SPECIFIC exception type [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException] in the code below
# and use ONE generic catch block instead. Such a catch block then handles ALL error types, so you would need to
# add the logic to handle different error types differently by yourself.


# catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
# NOTE: When you use a SPECIFIC catch block, exceptions thrown by -ErrorAction Stop MAY LACK
# some InvocationInfo details such as ScriptLineNumber.
# REMEDY: If that affects you, remove the SPECIFIC exception type [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException] in the code below
# and use ONE generic catch block instead. Such a catch block then handles ALL error types, so you would need to
# add the logic to handle different error types differently by yourself.
{
  # get error record
  [Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]$e = $_

  # retrieve information about runtime error
  $info = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Exception = $e.Exception.Message
    Reason    = $e.CategoryInfo.Reason
    Target    = $e.CategoryInfo.TargetName
    Script    = $e.InvocationInfo.ScriptName
    Line      = $e.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
    Column    = $e.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine
  }

  # output information. Post-process collected info, and log info (optional)
  $info
}

{
  # get error record
  [Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]$e = $_

  # retrieve information about runtime error
  $info = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Exception = $e.Exception.Message
    Reason    = $e.CategoryInfo.Reason
    Target    = $e.CategoryInfo.TargetName
    Script    = $e.InvocationInfo.ScriptName
    Line      = $e.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
    Column    = $e.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine
  }

  # output information. Post-process collected info, and log info (optional)
  $info#>
}


# Oppretter WindowsForm / GUI for applikasjonen.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Heading
$form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Test-Heading'
$form.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList (400, 600)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

#OK-knapp
$OKButton = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList (170, 485)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList (100, 50)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

#Avbryt-knapp
$CancelButton = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList (270, 485)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList (100, 50)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Avbryt'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

# Tekst-label
$label = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList (10, 20)
$label.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList (280, 20)
$label.Text = 'Test-Label'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

# Liste-boks
$listBox = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList (10, 40)
$listBox.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList (360, 20)
$listBox.Height = 400


# Hashtable made to be able to show one text in the listbox, but return a different value.
$TESThash = @{
    'TEST1' = '1'
    'TEST2' = '2'
    'TEST3' = '3'

}

# Listbox-objects, one listbox-item pr. line.
$null =  $listBox.Items.Add('TEST1')
$null =  $listBox.Items.Add('TEST2')
$null =  $listBox.Items.Add('TEST3')

$form.Controls.Add($listBox)

$form.Topmost = $true

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{

  $TESTalias = $TESThash[$listBox.SelectedItem]

  # File to change
  $file = "C:\Users\$User\ist.ini"

  # Get file content and store it into $content variable
  $content = Get-Content -Path $file

  # Endrer tekst på linje 33 og linje 53
  $content[32] = 'PICTUREPATH=K:\Opplaering\Bilete\'+"$TESTalias"
  $content[52] = 'PICTUREPATH=K:\Opplaering\Bilete\'+"$TESTalias"


  # Set the new content
  $content | Set-Content -Path $file
  if(!(Test-Path -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Uninstall\ExtensBildeFix")){
  New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ExtensBildeFix" -Value "1"}

$form.Controls|%{$_.Text}}
```

Comment: Added sample-code so it's easier to understand what I'm trying to get help with :)

The script works fine.

However when I compile it, it will just edit the lines 33 and 53 of the configuration file to "'PICTUREPATH=K:\Opplaering\Bilete\" instead of "'PICTUREPATH=K:\Opplaering\Bilete\[RETURNED_VALUE_FROM_LISTBOX] here.

Comment: Surely you need to use  $TESTalias = $TESThash[$listBox.SelectedItem.Text] rather than the object?     Also - do you have to use the hash table? Why not just do this: $content[32] = 'PICTUREPATH=K:\Opplaering\Bilete\'+($listbox.selecteditem.text).replace('TEST','')

Comment: Can you explain it's better to do it that way?

I use the hashtable to be able to give the listbox-item a name/location (so it's easier for the user to understand).
And then convert the name into a shortening based on that name.

ie. Oslo Airport = OSL

So when the user clicks the listbox-item and then ok,  OSL is supposed to be added to the path.

As I said in my initial post, it works perfectly fine when running it as a regular script. But as soon as I compile to exe it won't work anymore :)

I want to understand why, but this stumps me.

Thanks for your reply by the way.

Comment: Ah ok, then yes you need the Hash table. Anyway $TESThash[$listBox.SelectedItem] returns an object. $TESThash[$listBox.SelectedItem.Text] returns the value of the text field. This could be causing the issue

Comment: Did you tyr making both $TESThash and $TESTalias global variables?

Comment: Yes. I tried making both global vars. I did that by doing this editing the variable name from $TESThash and TESTalias to $Script:TESThash nad $Script:TESTalias.

Comment: What output do you get when you run as .exe? I've just compiled your script using ps2exe and run with a test ini file and it works perfectly.
Try compiling without the -noconsole switch and add the following commands at the end: Write-host $TESTalias , Pause. You can then see what value is being added.

Comment: I did what you said and it returned the expected result as it should. But the problem still remained in regards  the executable not doing what it should.

I recompiled the script in PS2EXE again, first without the -noconsole switch and then with the noconsole-switch.

**IT WORKS!** After adding the -noconsole parameter. What the h#%¤ is this sorcery?
I've compiled using ISESteroids with ALL console-modes, used several gui-tools and had the exact same issue (when selecting noconsole the form wouldn't even display). When adding the same switch in PS2EXE it works flawlessly. I feel dumb :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script worked fine all along. The problem was that the console-mode was not set correctly using either of the tools I used to compile.

After a nudge from "Scepticalist" i re-tried PS2EXE using the -noconsole switch, and it all worked perfectly.

Thank you!

Slightly annoying that the issue turned out to be as simple as that, but glad it got sorted :)